# Euler Challenge 349: Javascript: Code works but is too slow

Tags: javascript, optimization

I've been trying to code a solution to project Euler's problem 349 in javascript (I know this is a less than ideal language for this). The problem is basically Langtons ant but with 10^18 moves. A full description of the challenge can be seen [here](http://projecteuler.net/problem=349) . I managed to get some working code where I use a array as the grid of squares. If a value in the array is 1 then its black, if its 0, its white. Now the problem with this code is it is much too slow, it takes about 28 seconds to calculate 1 million moves. Any ideas on how I might go about optimizing this code?

```
 var grid = [];
 for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    grid.push(0);
 }
 var sum = 0;
 var orientation = 0;
 var position = (grid.length / 2);
 var rowLength = Math.sqrt(1000000);
 var mover = function() {
        switch (orientation) {
        case -360:
            position += 1;
            break;
        case -270:
            position += rowLength;
            break;
        case -180:
            position -= 1;
            break;
        case -90:
            position -= rowLength;
            break;
        case 0:
            position += 1;
            break;
        case 90:
            position += rowLength;
            break;
        case 180:
            position -= 1;
            break;
        case 270:
            position -= rowLength;
            break;
        case 360:
            position += 1;
            break;
        default:
            alert("fault in clockwise switch");
        }
    };
 var check = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) { //counts all blacks (1's)
            if (grid[i]) {
                sum += 1;
            }
        }
    };
 var movement = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { // end condition of i is number of steps
            if (grid[position]) //if it lands on a black
            {
                grid[position] = 0;
                if (orientation === 360) { //keeps orientation below 360
                    orientation = 0;
                }
                orientation += 90; //90 degree clockwise turn
                mover();
            } else if (!grid[position]) { //if it lands on a white 
                if (!grid[position]) {
                    if (orientation === -360) {
                        orientation = 0;
                    }
                    grid[position] = 1;
                    orientation -= 90;
                    mover();
                }
            }
        }
    };
 movement();
 check();
 console.log(position);
 console.log(sum);
```

Comment: You can't bruteforce this one. Here's a hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton's_ant#Emergent_order

Answer (score 0):

Langtons's ant eventually falls into a pattern and builds a "highway". You don't need to actually run for 10^18 iterations to identify this pattern and use it to predict the number of black squares at any future time.